# Time of Closing a Document/Page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, lotus-notes

I need to get the span of time when closing a document or page using javascript. I need to get exactly the time from when the user submits/close a document until it closes completely or move to another page and store the value. I tried searching this question for almost two days but to no avail if I missed it and it's already existing please do share the link here.

We need to store the time for a page to load and time for a page to close when it is submitted or closed. I was able to use "window.performance" in order to get the time for a page to load. Now I need to figure out a how to get the time when being closed, using "window.performance" is not applicable based on my analysis.

I tried trying to play around using the onbeforeunload and onunload but I am unsuccessful in getting the time. This is for a Lotus Notes Web Application it would be better if someone can share a link or answer here related to Lotus Notes Concept but a pure javascript concept would also be a big help.

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` events cannot be stopped, so you will have little to no time to record and submit a timespan. There's no guarantee that your code will finish executing in those event handlers.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no way to be able to keep the time when a document or page is being closed?

Comment: How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: It would be best if the time from when it was submitted/closed until it really closed or redirected to another page. If it's not possible then what can you suggest as an alternative? or is it basically impossible? Thanks a lot.